# Why my page will not change when use history.push using react-router

Tags: html, reactjs, react-router

I have a single page application webpage...
Below is some of my code...

```
var createBrowserHistory = require('history/lib/createBrowserHistory');
var history = createBrowserHistory();
history.push('account/person');
```

When I click a button, I can see the browser's URL change to http://IP/account/person, but nothing happened, still on same page.

But if I replace url directly to http://IP/account/person by typing, the page will map to correct page.

Below is my react router config

```
 <Router history={new createBrowserHistory()}> 
  <Route path='/account' component={Gift}></Route>                                                                                                                                     
  <Route path='/account/person' component={Person}></Route>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
</Router>
```

Why this happened?

Comment: Show us your router config.

Comment: @azium, add route config

Comment: probably use `router.push()` here instead of `history.push`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to import a different object to handle the programmatic routing:

https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/NavigatingOutsideOfComponents.md

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'
browserHistory.push('/account/person')
```